# getting values per week in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How do I get a `hash` with the number of objects in a class for each week, i.e. Objects per week?

If there are no objects present for a week it should return 0.

I'd also like to return the start date of each week, entries span `2009-10-01 to 2011-5-18`, but will be updated. I'm looking for a little function I can call on `@objects`, which will be different counts depending on the scope of dates requested.

I have a feeling the [rails sum()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) method will be useful, but I'm not sure how to ask by week.

I hope that's clear :) Thanks in advance

Comment: This is trying to show objects by date, ordered by date:
 
`Object.count(:occured_on, :group => "DATE(occured_on)").order(:occured_on)`

but returns 
`NoMethodError: undefined method `order' for #<ActiveSupport::OrderedHash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Hash[
  Quote.count(:id, group: :created_at).group_by {|k,_| 
    k.beginning_of_week 
  }.map { |week, ary| 
    [week, ary.map(&:last).sum]
  }.sort_by &:first
]
```

Comment: Brilliant BrioSatse, that does the trick! It comes back in an unknown order, how would I add .order(:created_at) to this? Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I will research all the methods used. Fantastic :)

Comment: Little followup question: how would you then wrap this in a method such as `total_count` as opposed to `count`.

See http://rubydoc.info/github/amatsuda/kaminari/Kaminari/ActiveRecordRelationMethods:total_count